# When an icalendar (ical) is updated, could java get the new event details and do something?

Tags: java, icalendar, ical4j

In a java existing application, I am asking me if it's possible to do the following:

- A user create a new event in his ical with Google Calendar(Agenda) for example
- The java programm detect that the calendar have been updated, that a new event/rendez vous has been created
- The java programm get new event details and store this detail in mysql database for example

Do you know if it's possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

yes this is possible, the only thing you have to keep track of is the uid of the events: a new uid indicates a new event and you also need to keep track of the sequence property to detect changes in the event.